# Looking for Java server library/framework for server management interface

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and have developed a Java server application that receives small pieces of mass data in a proprietary protocol via TCP from many clients on the internet, sends it to a Postgres database (JDBC) and communicates with other modules using sockets, too.

So far I am using Java NIO for socket I/O and slf4j/logback for logging, apart from that only standard Java stuff.

Now I need to implement the administration stuff that every professional server application needs, e.g. switching logging on and off with fine granularity, make the server reread its configuration, shut the server down cleanly, reset client connections, get usage statistics, etc. 
So I'll need to implement some administration interface using Sockets and design some communications protocol, etc. or something like that.

This is such a common task in creation of server apps that I thing someone must have had the idea before to create libraries for this.

Are there any common frameworks for such tasks either in the Java Standard Libraries or from other sources that you can recommend?
The library must be able to run on Linux and Mac OS X and must be Open Source, license preferrably BSD-style or similar.

Bye, Matthias

Comment: And soon you'll need user management, audit and security, and you'll have to rewrite it using JavaEE ...

Comment: Are you using Netty?  Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use JMX and JConsole to do it.  Expose your server components as MBeans and grant write access.